# python: lock but based on a parameter

Tags: python, locking

I would like to use something that lock the code in python for being thread safe, but based on a specific parameter that I pass.

For example my app is used by many users having an own id.

I would like to lock that part of code only for the very same user.

So if a user with id 123 pass in the part of code with the lock, the lock is valid only for the  same user id 123, while if it's passing user 345 he has a own separated lock.

Is there something to do this? Because I read about the lock of threading module but I haven't found anything to make the lock valid only if there is a same passed parameter

Comment: I'm a little confused. You want to lock the code, but still allow another user in the same code, just with a different lock? That defeats the purpose of the lock, stops being threadsafe.

Comment: What you really want is a `dict` of individual locks. Say, `d = {userid: Lock() for userid in [123, 345, ...]}`. Then user 123 has to acquire `d[123]`, user 345 has to acquire `d[345]`, etc. (What this lock actually *protects* is another matter, as mentioned by Chrismon Chin.)

Comment: Thanks. I need this because I want that one user does only one operation and can do the following once the previous is completed and responded. So another thread, in the same time, could run the command for another user, but not for him because he has already an operation in progress